# Clearing each node in a linked structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nodes

I am stuck here. 
Can you please help me?
I can't seem to implement this function “freeThis”.
I am trying to free  nodes in a linked list.

Structure

```
struct node {
    unsigned x;
    double y;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node Nodes, *This;
```

Declaration of the function

```
void freeThis(This *);
```

Implementation of the function

```
void freeThis(This *head)
{
   This * tmp;

   while (head != NULL)
    {
       tmp = head;

       *head = *head->next; /*error is here I think */

       free(tmp);
    }

}
```

UPDATE!

When there is a function declared like this

```
void freeNodes(Nodes *);
```

implemented like this

```
void freeNodes(Nodes *a)

    {
        free(a);
        printf(“sucess”);
    }
```

how would I use this function ?

Like this ?

```
freeNodes(*tmp);
```

Comment: Short answer: dont't typedef. typedef is only intended to confuse you. (until you know better)

Answer (score 1):

`This` is a pointer type: `typedef struct node Nodes, *This;`

Note that you don't need a pointer to pointer, a single pointer is enough, so change:

```
void freeThis(This *head) /* head is a pointer to pointer */
{
   This * tmp;
```

to

```
void freeThis(This head)
{
   This tmp;
```

and

```
   *head = *head->next;
```

to

```
   head = head->next;
```

Comment: `(*head) = (*head)->next;` This worked but i ran into another problem

Comment: @billybob I doubt it worked. Semantically, it's incorreect. The idiomatic way to free a link list is not to replace the **nodes** themselves but only the pointer (think about it, it's quite obvious why). Also, don't hide pointers behind a typedef. Get rid of `This` altogether, and just use `Node *`.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, the problem is here:

```
*head = *head->next;
```

This is because of operator precedence. -> is evaluated first and then *.

Try

```
*head = (*head)->next;
```

For the UPDATE:

If you have declared temp as

```
Nodes * temp
```

then call function

```
freeNodes(temp)
```

Comment: How have you declared the temp?

Comment: oh that tmp was suppose to go with what i posted earlier. instead of using `free(tmp);` i am trying to use `void freeNodes(Nodes *a)` which itself will use `free(tmp);` later but i need to do this

Comment: That works, but you don't need a pointer to pointer, see my answer.

Comment: @AlterMann: I know that pointer to pointer is not required. I just gave the solution for the problem.

Comment: @Arpit, it was a comment for OP in reply to "**yes that works**", your answer is correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also...

```
  void freeThis(Nodes **head)
  {
    Nodes *tmp;

    while (*head)
    {
      tmp = *head;/*first node to be delete*/
      *head = *head->next;/*2nd node is updated as headpointer*/
      free(tmp);/* freeing first node & here you can call your freeNodes function...*/
     }

 }
```